# How to populate a window with a dictionary of images?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, dictionary

I have a GUI with a button that will open a new window. **As soon as** the window opens I need it to be filled with a sires of pictures that I have stored in a dictionary of (string,bitmap) with the string representing the path name. Obviously I need to iterate across the dictionary but I don't know what code to use to display the pictures. Is there anyway to make a loop that will automatically display the images in a set size.

For a good example of the output I'm looking for, think windows explorer thumbnails when browsing a folder of pictures.

I know very little about working with images or GUIs so any assistance would be appreciated.

As of now my this is the code I have:

```
MyPalletGui.Show();
        PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
        Dictionary<string,Bitmap> MyPallet = MyImageCollection.ToDictionary();
        int xcor = 0;
        int ycor = 0;
        foreach (Bitmap curtImage in MyPallet.Values){
            xcor += 50;
            ycor += 50;
            myPicBox.Location = new Point(xcor, ycor);
            myPicBox.Width = 50;
            myPicBox.Height = 50;
            myPicBox.Visible = true;
            myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(curtImage);
            this.MyPalletGui.Controls.Add(myPicBox);
```

I need to work with the x and y coordinates more, but the code above displays nothing.

Comment: Don't understand what's your problem, this is pretty basic stuff... What have you tried so far?

Comment: It may be basic but like i said im not very experienced in images or guis. I did try to loop to the dictionary but I got tripped up by the difference between a paintevent and a Event. Also I was told that i was trying to display the images to the button and not a gui. Basically Im starting from scratch

Comment: Iterate through the dictionary and add a picture box to your form for each.

Comment: But if I do that will it be organized by columns and rows? Also they have to be thumbnail sized and i don't know how to do that. Can I see an example of what you mean exactly?

Comment: If you organize them like that, of course. Did you at least try something? Anything? I understand you're a beginner, but that doesn't mean you can come here and ask for a complete solution without showing your effort. There are several ways of doing what you're after, but we're not here to provide a support for people who are simply too lazy to do a basic research. How do you think we've learned stuff we know now? Open Google, do some research, try something and then come back with the code you've created and ask a specific question. So far it seems you haven't even opened VS.

Comment: `I did try to loop to the dictionary` if that's true, show us the code. Oli has already provided you a hint what to do.

Comment: Ok so I've been working at it and ill add what i have to the question. Also I would have posted what i had tried before but it totally incorrect so i deleted it entirely.

Comment: One problem I see: `PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();` needs to be inside the loop. You need to create a separate picturebox for each image.

Comment: uh... yeah I can't believe i missed that thank you. That got the images to display. One other thing anyone have suggestions on how to work the x y coordinates? As of now they make the pictures diagonal I need them to be in rows and columns.

Comment: You are increasing both x and y values by 50 each time so they will be positioned diagonally. Just increase the x value. Then each time you want a new row, increase the y value and reset the x value.